# Once you download the PIA for Office 2010, how do you get Visual C# to place it in your Add References .NET menu?

Tags: c#, smtp, outlook-2010, office-pia

I've never posted so I'm a little nervous, but I've been making a program to compile and send an email after gathering the computer name and IP. I've got an understanding how to do do that just fine, however, I'm trying to use MS Outlook to send the mail. I've used the following information on how to format the emails to send out (hope it's not bad form to link to other info sites):

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/165548/C-Code-snippet-to-send-an-Email-with-attachment-fr

That seems very strait forward, but I can't seem to locate the library for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll in the .NET Add Reference window. I've located, downloaded and installed the Office 2010 PIA, but that doesn't seem to auto populate the dll files into the reference window. Where should I look on my system for these files? I don't remember defining a location for the PIA Installation.

Comment: There, now you have enough rep. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not in the .NET References, it's in the COM References.  Look for the Microsoft Outlook Object library and select it there.

Also make sure that if you are distributing the application to other machines that you copy the dll from your `bin\release` folder along with your executable.

Comment: Found it! Thanks to both of you! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched in the COM tab? It is there

[image]

Comment: Way to one up me with the screenshot! ;)

Comment: @Evanlewis You'll have already heard. *A picture is worth a thousand words*, good also your reference to the redistribution issue.

Comment: No I haven't. That's cool, but which one should I use for what I'm doing? MS Outlook View Control, Social provider Extensibility? I don't really know which does what.... Found it! Thanks to both of you! ^_^ I gave Evan the check mark, sorry Steve.

Comment: Microsoft Outlook Object library. The exact version depends on which version of Office is installed on your PC. Remember that the target PC should have Outlook installed for your app to work (In addition to the PIA files)

Comment: Yeah, my rep isn't up there enough yet, but as soon as it is, I'll give you karma! ^_^